# Add a new index to a multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have a 2 index (Date, Product) dataframe that looks like this:

```
[Date,Product]  price
D1 P1          1
   P2          4
D2 P1          2
   P2          2
D3 P1          2
   P2          3
...
```

How can I add a P3 lvl from date D2 so it looks like the below?

```
[Date,Product]  price
    D1 P1          1
       P2          4
    D2 P1          2
       P2          2
       P3          3
    D3 P1          2
       P2          3
       P3          1
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(data=[3,1],index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['D2','D3'],['P3']]),columns=['price'])]).sort_index()
Out[68]: 
              price
Date Product       
D1   P1           1
     P2           4
D2   P1           2
     P2           2
     P3           3
D3   P1           2
     P2           3
     P3           1
```